# Find the first to last alphabet in a string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am new to Python and got pretty confused when reading the regex documentation. From what I understand, `re.search` searches everywhere in a string while `re.match` only searches the start of the string. But when do I have to use `re.compile`?

I tried playing around with regex but could not get it to work. If have a string that is mixed with letters, punctuations, numbers and spaces, how can I obtain the part of the string with alphabets?

```
import re
a = "123,12    jlkjL kSljdf   12.2"
test = re.search('^[a-zA-Z]', a)
print test
```

The output I am trying to get is `jlkjL kSljdf`.

Comment: [`re.search(r'[a-zA-Z ]+', a).group().strip()`](http://ideone.com/EwO0Jb) Include a space to the character class and set a `+` (1 or more) quantifier on it. Strip the redundant whitespace with `strip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `re.compile` to compile a regex object before using the regex operation.

There are two options to ahcieve what you want: matching the letters with spaces and then stripping redundant whitespace or removing all non-letter symbols from start/end:

```
import re
a = "123,12    jlkjL kSljdf   12.2"
rg = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z ]+')
mtch = rg.search(a)
if mtch:
    print (mtch.group().strip()) # => jlkjL kSljdf

# Stripping non-letters from the start/end
rx = re.compile(r'^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$')
print(rx.sub('', a)) # => jlkjL kSljdf
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/nuzgCd)

In the first approach, include a space to the character class and set a `+` (1 or more occurrences) quantifier on it.

In the second approach, `^[^a-zA-Z]+` matches 1 or more  (`+`) characters other than letters (`[^a-zA-Z]`) at the start of the string (`^`)  OR (`|`) 1 or more chars other than letters at the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still unclear about the `re.compile` part. Why do I need to compile the regex object? Does `re.compile` help present the result in a "useful" way? Because I tried `print re.search(r'[a-zA-Z ]+',a)` but it returns `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10f7503d8>`, which is not useful in this case.

In the second approach, why did you have to use two `^` in `^[^a-zA-Z]+`?

Comment: I am feeding my daughter now, but in short: 1) compiling a regex object makes a regex operation perform quicker and it is good when you need to re-use it a lot of times, 2) `^` outside the brackets matches the start of a string, 3) the `[^..]`  negates the character class, 4) the `.group()` accesses the match value, if you print `re.search()` it prints the match *object*.